# Asp.net mvc displaying results about a selection being made

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am porting an application from wpf to asp.net mvc.
In the wpf I have a view in which the user selects from a combobox the name of a client and then in some textboxes, next to the combobox, some specific information about the client will show up (email, address, etc). In wpf I fill all this information in an observablecollection that resides in memory and when the client changes, I retrieve the other ones from the collection so it won't fo through the database.

Is there any way in asp.net mvc I can do this ? Or every time the client changes i will fetch from the database the extra information ? (will be slow)
This controls is just to select the client (and the extra information to help the user) so it should be fast.

How would you do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to make a call back to the server for every selection, then you should look at a solution whereby you pre-fetch all the data that you need and hold it in a javascript object.  Then you could write a javascript method that would fire on the selection DOM event.

Comment: This was also on my mind but I didn't know where to keep all the information. I am new to javascript. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you are looking for is Session. You can pull the list from the database once, store it in session, and then reference session as needed for each client's data. This recommendation is based on presumption that the list is not being modified elsewhere, and therefore, invalidating the version of the list you have stored in Session.

Using Session in ASP.NET - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: is it efficient to store information for hundreds of clients in the session (which i think will be stored, using cookies, on the client side)?

Comment: Efficient is a relative term so it is tough to answer that question without more information. The answer is dependent on how much information each client record includes.